# Recover a deleted contact without iCloud backups

Tags: ios, contacts

When I was deleting contacts on my iPhone yesterday, I mistakenly deleted another one with similar name! Any idea how to get it back? I don't have any backups to iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:

1. Logon to iCloud.com
2. Go to Settings
3. At the bottom left you will see Advanced and "Restore Contacts"

From there you will be able to restore a previous backup that iCloud has done.

Comment: Thank you, but i don't have backup in icloud...