# Restore deleted contacts from iCloud without iCloud backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, contacts

iphone se ios 11.4

I am following this post, but the answer there doesnt answer the question.
[Recover a deleted contact without iCloud backups](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240249/recover-a-deleted-contact-without-icloud-backups)

I deleted a contact accidentally, and the contacts synchronized immediately with iCloud. Is is possible to recover this deleted contact, if icloud back up is not turned on?

I downloaded a recovery software and I can see the deleted contact, but ofcourse these softwares would only allow to recover the deleted contact after a fat price. Since, its just this one contact, I was wondering if there is any alternative solution?

Comment: If it's just one contact, and you know what the contact is, why don't you just recreate it?  And then turn backups on.

Comment: If you have another device that hasn't synced with iCloud yet you can recover it from that device. For example, if you have a Mac that's turned off you can stop it from connecting to your network (turn off your router or modem first) then access the Contact application.

Comment: @MarcWilson the recovery software just shows the name, but hides the contact details.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud automatically archives the contacts ( there is a max of 10 archives  ). The contacts can be restored via the web browser, even if no iCloud backups is switched on on the device.

In the webbrowser, click on settings and then contacts and then restore archived contacts.

Before the contacts are restored, iCloud makes another archive of the current contacts. Therefore, after retrieving a lost contact, write down the contact details and then one can go back to and restore the latest archive.